# Cannot read jsonl string unless I save it and read from disk

Tags: python, json

Disclaimer: I could not come up with a better title, I am definitely open to suggestions.

### 1. Decoding and json.loads():

I am currently trying to read a json from a decoded string with the following code:

```py
def _load_values_from_json(jsonl: str) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    json_values = list()
    # jsonl is a byte string `b'...'`
    for line in jsonl.decode():
        breakpoint()
        json_line = json.loads(line)
        json_values.append(json_line)
```

This yields me an output such as:

```
# Breakpoint
>>> line
'{'
```

But, if I save the string as a `.json` and open and repeat the process later:

### 2. Saving decoded string and reading from disk:

```py
def _load_values_from_json(jsonl: str) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    json_values = list()
    _save_jsonl_file(jsonl)
    jsonl_from_file = _read_jsonl_file()
    for line in jsonl_from_file:
        breakpoint()
        json_line = json.loads(line)
        json_values.append(json_line)


def _save_jsonl_file(jsonl):
    with open("/tmp/jsonl.json", "w") as fout:
        fout.write(jsonl.decode())


def _read_jsonl_file():
    with open("/tmp/jsonl.json", "r") as fin:
        return fin.readlines()
```

This yields the json correctly read:

```
# Breakpoint

>>> line
'{"name":"Foo"}'

# Continue

>>> line
'{"name":"Loo"}'
```

### Additional Information

Both cases I am calling the function with:

```py
# Loaded from TensorFlow Dataset eagerly
inputs = inputs.numpy() 

# Inputs comes as byte string
values = _load_values_from_json(inputs)
```

Can anyone help with on understanding this behaviour or what am I doing wrong in the 1. case?

I do not want to I/O everytime I read a json

Comment: Do you have an example of how you're calling `_load_values_from_json` in the first case? it seems like you're sending in just the lines from a file. Add an example that is actually runnable - i.e. add a byte sequence that shows the issue.

Comment: What version of Python are you using, and what does the actual `.json` file look like? And why are you expecting it to make sense to iterate over the lines of a JSON string? You do understand that newlines are not significant in the JSON format, right?

Comment: @MatsLindh I have added the function call I am using and now I am working to retrieve the original inputs used in the function, will update ASAP.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the .jsonl file has 1 json object per line, that is why I want to parse it line after line. I will add this explanation to the question,

Comment: Actually, the code you're showing can't possibly be right. Type annotations indicate Python 3.x, in which case there is no `str.decode` (because `str` is already a Unicode string type). Either way it certainly wouldn't produce a `bytes` (are you thinking of `.encode`?), and you don't want to feed `bytes` to the json library anyway.

Comment: If you iterate over a *str*, that will iterate over individual characters in the string. On the other hand, when reading it from a file, you appear to be using `readlines`, which returns a *list*.

Comment: You are right: I am using Python 3.8.

Yet, `str.decode()` works right, I do not understand why it shouldn't

Comment: @deceze Can you suggest a way I can iterate over a `str` line by line?

Comment: Be consistent and make it a *list of strings*? Perhaps by splitting on `'\n'`?

Comment: Presumably because you are actually receiving a `bytes` and your type annotation is incorrect (and not being checked). Anyway, it's as @deceze told you - whether `bytes` or `str`, iteration doesn't give you newline-separated lines, it gives you individual elements.

Comment: I will try splitting on `\n`, thank you very much.

@KarlKnechtel I sadly cannot run mypy verification at this moment as my input/output is streamed from Google Storage using TFRecords, so yes, the typing may be wrong. But `jsonl` argument is a string in the format `b'xxx'`

Comment: Splitting on "\n" worked. I feel a little stupid not thinking about it before. But, thank you all. @KarlKnechtel I will review my type hints, thank you for that also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the question comments, the problem was quite simple/obvious:

### Solution

It is necessary to split the decoded `bytes` with `"\n"`, as `.readlines()` does.

```py
def _load_values_from_json(jsonl: bytes) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    values = list()
    jsonl = _read_jsonl(jsonl)
    for line in jsonl.split("\n"): # Here!
        json_obj = json.loads(line)
        values.append(json_obj)


def _read_jsonl(jsonl: bytes) -> str:
    return jsonl.decode()
```